# Hide other elements in list

Tags: javascript, angular, angular6, viewchild

I have the below code:

```
<li *ngFor="let item of Array let i = index">
  <span>
    <label (dblclick)="editTag($event,i)">
      {{item.tag}}
    </label>
    <input type="text" #tagInput  />
  </span>
</li>
```

The code is in a `for` loop. When I click on a label, all labels should be hidden and the input should be visible. Currently, when I click on each label, the other remain open. How do I hide the other span when clicking on any item?

I have below code in .ts

```
@ViewChild('tagInput') tagNameTextInput: ElementRef;
  editTag(event: any,index: any) {
    //console.info(event);
    this.tagNameTextInput.nativeElement.hidden = true;
    this.tagNameTextInput.nativeElement.previousElementSibling.hidden = false;
    let initialValue = event.target.childNodes[0].nodeValue.trim();
    event.target.hidden = true;
    event.target.nextElementSibling.hidden = false;
    event.target.nextElementSibling.value = initialValue;
    console.log(index);
    // this.checkListNameHidden = true;
    // this.checkListNameTextInput.nativeElement.value = initialValue;
    // this.checkListNameTextInput.nativeElement.focus();


    event.stopPropagation();
  }
```

How to solve this?

Comment: Can you post your full html with `ngFor`.

Comment: updated html with for

Comment: Have you tried this : `@ViewChildren('tagInput') tagNameTextInput: QueryList<ElementRef>` instead of `@ViewChild('tagInput') tagNameTextInput: ElementRef;`. because in your for loop element ref does not keep unique.

Comment: Could you create working demo? You should hide elements using `NgIf` but it's not clear whether you can access other array elements in this listener

Comment: @Md.ParvezAlam, Also try `@ViewChildren` instaed of `@ViewChild`. because you have multiple children. I have updated my comment.

Comment: @ShashikantDevani where will I find QueryList

Comment: Import from @angular/core : Reference link https://angular.io/api/core/QueryList

Comment: Yep, got that, and looks like it is working

Comment: Thanks @ShashikantDevani brother, it is working fine

Comment: Your welcome, Okk will add as answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have multiple children, So you need to use `@ViewChildren` instead of `@ViewChild`.

Also in your `ngFor` loop you do not have unique template reference `#tagInput`. Use `QueryList` with `ElementRef`.

Try : `@ViewChildren('tagInput') tagNameTextInput: QueryList<ElementRef>;`

instead of

`@ViewChild('tagInput') tagNameTextInput: ElementRef;`.

Import QueryList from `@angular/core`.

Like this `import { Component, QueryList } from '@angular/core';`

Answer (score 1):

the best aproach is add a new property to "item", (e.g. called "editing") so

```
<li *ngFor="let item of Array let i = index">
  <span>
    <label *ngIf="!item.editing" (dblclick)="item.editing=true;">
      {{item.tag}}
    </label>
    <input *ngIf="item.editing" [(ngModel)]="item.tag" type="text" (blur)="item.editing=false"  />
  </span>
</li>
```

See several things:

1.-in a click of label, the variable becomes true, so the inpùt is showed

2.-in blur of item, the variable becomes false, so the label is showed

3.-Use [(ngModel)] to relation between the input and the value