# Set ViewChild based on a condition

Tags: angular, angular7

In my Angular 7 application, I have have over 5000 elements in a tree view. I need to access the DOM element that has been selected, so I can use something like [`scrollIntoView`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView()). Basically my pseudo code would look like this:

```
if selected element is not visible
    call scrollIntoView on the element
```

Problem is, I need to call this every time the keyboard is pressed (arrows up and down). I have tried passing in the `$event` to find the previous element, next element, and so on, so I can simply call `scrollIntoView()` on that element, but I don't think that's a very good idea. It involves a lot of recursion (because the tree view is nested) and my HTML can never change (unless I update the code as well).

Is it possible to set [`ViewChild()`](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild) based on a condition? That way I can simply do `this.selectedElement.nativeElement.scrollIntoView()` or something like that. Unless there's a better idea?

Comment: Maybe this link will help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53149659/hide-other-elements-in-list/53151135#53151135.

Comment: @ShashikantDevani Except I only need my one and only element.

Comment: Then you can pass index from `ngFor`

Comment: @ShashikantDevani What would that help?

Answer (score 2):

Well that's not very clear, but if I got it correctly, you can use `@ViewChildren`, which is basically several `@ViewChild`.

[This stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zir5pa?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) shows how you can use it, and as you can see, it's very easy to use.

```js
import { Component, QueryList, ElementRef, ViewChildren } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<hello name="{{ name }}"></hello>
<div 
  *ngFor="let index of [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]" 
  (mouseover)="hovered(divs)"
  #divs>
  This is the div n° {{ index }}
</div>`,
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {

  @ViewChildren('divs') divs: QueryList<ElementRef<HTMLDivElement>>;

  name = 'Angular';

  hovered(div: HTMLDivElement) {
    // Getting from the query list
    const corresponding = this.divs.find(_div => _div.nativeElement === div).nativeElement;

    // they are the same
    console.log(corresponding);
    console.log(corresponding === div);
    console.log(div);
  }
}
```

Comment: Problem is I only want ONE ViewChild (or ViewChildren). ViewChildren could work, but I need a way to conditionally say "if my viewchild has xxx property", that I can set somehow, then it could work. I just need ONE element, which is the selected one.

Comment: Well as you can see in the stackblitz, it only returns a single element, which contains anything you have declared on it (for instance, an `active` class).

Comment: Okay, let me break it down a bit more, so it's easier to understand. Look at this StackBlitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-j7ovfn - The "corresponding" element is never updated to the new one, even though I change the selected to a new one. To test it out, click on the first element in the list and press on your down arrow key.

Comment: That's because your code isn't supposed to do what you expect it to do. In [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-t8hvav?file=src/app/app.component.ts), you can see that it's workign pretty well (I didn't secure the arrow keys so don't click on the first or last item to test it out !)

Comment: What about nested elements? As I explained I have in the OP. Working with simple HTML where I only have DIVs right after each other is easy enough. But when it comes to nested elements (think about ul and li tags), it's a whole different story. Here's an example (only arrow down works in the demo) where I have nested ul and li tags: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-eavqd6 (a bit different than the other StackBlitz you provided, but it should make sense).

Comment: Recursivity doesn't matter, as long as the elements are the same. [The same stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-t8hvav?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) shows you that : you can declare several template variables, they will still reference the elements of the loop. Try it yourself, see how it behaves like the previous un-nested version.

Comment: Really interesting way to use .toArray() and just +1 or -1 depending on the elements. However, it doesn't work in my example for some reason. My root elements (the ones that have children) are added first, then the children of the first element is added afterwards. Not sure if it's because I use ng-template and ng-container, though.

Comment: Well I can't tell, I'm explaining a concept here more than resolving an issue ; but I do agree that it seems you're doing very complicated things : maybe try to keep it simple, like I did ? Anyway, I hope that it will help you, because really, that's the only solution that comes to my mind for your issue. So if I can't be of anymore help, then good luck with your project !